# Cannot find pylint

Tags: python

I installed `pylint` by `pip install pylint` :

```
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (2.5.3)
Requirement already satisfied: toml>=0.7.1 in 
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in     
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: isort<5,>=4.2.5 in 
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (4.3.21)
Requirement already satisfied: astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0 in 
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pylint) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mccabe<0.7,>=0.6 in 
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from pylint) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: lazy-object-proxy==1.4.* in 
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: typed-ast<1.5,>=1.4.0; implementation_name == "cpython" and python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt~=1.11 in 
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six~=1.12 in 
c:\users\horseman.mini\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from astroid<=2.5,>=2.4.0->pylint) (1.13.0)
```

But when I run in the directiy with file I want to check `pylint text.py` it writes

```
$ pylint test.py
bash: pylint: command not found
```

I didn't add path to pylint to PATH because I can't find its path. But when I run python and `import pylint` it imports ok. How could I run pylint from command line?

Comment: does `python -m pylint` work? the `-m` flag is how to run a module from command line.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes, it works with -m flag

Comment: so is `python -m pylint test.py` good enough for you? getting an alias to use directly `pylint` depends on platform.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen haven't seen pylint usage with `python -m` prefix, good, will use it that way. You can write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any python module can be run with `python -m MODULE` for instance I always use `python3 -m pip` since I can never manage to get the `pip` alias to work for the correct version . so you can use `pylint` as:

```
python -m pylint test.py
```